# Can Visual Studio's Javascript Intellisense be given a hint on the 'this' keyword?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2015, javascript-intellisense

I'm using the [Phaser framework](http://phaser.io/) to create a game within Visual Studio (2015, Community).

While I can successfully get Intellisense for smaller projects, that aren't OO, when I try switching over to object orientated JavaScript, I lose the Intellisense.

**boot.js**

```
/// <reference path="../lib/phaser-2.4.4.js" />
var BasicGame = {
};

BasicGame.Boot = function (game) {
    // This gives me Intellisense as expected:
    game.input.maxPointers = 1;
};

BasicGame.Boot.prototype = {
    init: function () {
    },

    preload: function () {
    },

    create: function () {
        // This is valid, but I don't get Intellisense.
        // Can I help VS understand what type 'this' is?
        this.state.start('Preloader');
    }
};
```

Can I, in some way, assist Visual Studio (2015/Code/higher) so that it understands what type the 'this' keyword is, in the case of the create method?

Other relevant files, for those not familiar with the Phaser framework OO template:

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>HTML5 Shoot 'em Up in an Afternoon</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" />
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            background: #333;
            margin: 0;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="lib/phaser-2.4.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="src/boot.js"></script>
    <script src="src/preloader.js"></script>
    <script src="src/mainMenu.js"></script>
    <script src="src/game.js"></script>
    <script src="src/app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="gameContainer"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

preloader.js, mainMenu.js and game.js are excluded for brevity. They contain setups much like boot.js, above.

**app.js**

```
window.onload = function () {
    var game = new Phaser.Game(800, 600, Phaser.AUTO, 'gameContainer');

    game.state.add('Boot', BasicGame.Boot);
    game.state.add('Preloader', BasicGame.Preloader);
    game.state.add('MainMenu', BasicGame.MainMenu);
    game.state.add('Game', BasicGame.Game);

    game.state.start('Boot');
};
```

Comment: What version of VS are you on - it improves with each release.  There's also [Code](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/code-vs.aspx) that's under much more rapid development, haven't tried it too much myself, but I understand it's intellisense for JS is pretty good.

Comment: Sorry, since I threw it in the tag I didn't mention the version in the question. 2015. I also have tried the Code version and it didn't provide it either. I'll edit my question; thanks!

Comment: Sorry - I completely missed the tag - that's a perfectly valid place for the version to be :)

Comment: have you tried [resharper](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/)?

Comment: I don't know a whole lot about phaser, but from what I can see here, unless there is some code you aren't showing, `BasicGame.Boot` doesn't have a `state`, so I don't think the problem is with Visual Studio, but with your claim that this code would be valid.

Comment: @JamesThorpe No problem! It also gave me a nudge to re-test in VS Code, and it looks like I can't even get Intellisense for the `game` parameter in `BasicGame.Boot`. :(
@andrew I do not have a license to ReSharper, and have not downloaded a trial to test. I guess I'd be more inclined to write my code the 'wrong' way than to drop the $250 for the license.

Comment: actually, the code *is* valid, but this is a pretty badly abused practice in JavaScript; you are essentially referencing a non-existent property of the object, which the JavaScript runtime will create a property for when it encounters the line at runtime;  at design time, there is no way for Visual Studio or any other lint / hint program to know about the property.

Comment: essentially, the way this framework is written, you won't get intellisense from it's libraries.

Comment: @Claies First comment: Updated with relevant context. I don't believe Phaser knowledge is needed. Second comment: That could be the case. RIght or wrong, this is what they're recommending. https://github.com/photonstorm/phaser/tree/master/resources/Project%20Templates/Basic

Comment: @Claies Your third/last comment: Well, that's awesome. You can count on at least one upvote if you can figure out a way to work around this issue. Otherwise I'm likely to just step back to their simpler ways while I'm learning the framework.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93302/discussion-between-claies-and-james-skemp).

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, I decided a bit over a month ago to start looking at developing in TypeScript instead of vanilla JavaScript.

This resulted in the Intellisense I wanted, and programming in a way that's a bit more efficient for me.

Thanks to Claies for his comments on my question which made me more receptive when I saw that I could learn TypeScript and get what I wanted from the framework.

Keeping the question open in case there ends up being a way to do what was originally asked.